# Error when trying to protect workbook and Protect Sharing

Tags: excel, vba

When executing code
Protect Workbook and Protect Sharing
Gives me an error:

"Run-time error '5': Invalid procedure call or argument"

Knowing if these operations were executed without code, there is no problem or error
Is there a solution to this problem?
And this code used

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ThisWorkbook.Protect Password:="123", Structure:=True, Windows:=False
ThisWorkbook.ProtectSharing SharingPassword:="123"
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Comment: **1.** Move `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` right after `ThisWorkbook.Protect Password:="123", Structure:=True, Windows:=False` **2.** Delete `, Structure:=True, Windows:=False` so that the code becomes `ThisWorkbook.Protect Password:="123"` Now try it :)